# Erlang vs Haskell : When does one prefer one over the other?

Tags: haskell, tcp, erlang

- When would one prefer [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/) over [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) ?
- Don't both can handle massive `TCP` traffic in one single process ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not find out for yourself? Pragmatic Press makes [Seven Languages in Seven Weeks](http://pragprog.com/book/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks) which includes Haskell and Erlang as two of the languages. While it won't make you an expert, you'll get a chance to kick the tires on both.

Erlang was built for high throughput, resilient network agents. Haskell has a different history, but I'm told it also has a good networking stack. I'm a huge fan of Erlang myself, and most answers that you get will probably be biased. But the best advice is to try it for yourself.

Comment: Also, check out http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cloud_Haskell if you're interested in an erlang like programming model in Haskell.